# Django select how to remember chosen value?

Tags: python, html, django, select, post

I have a select. On item change I reload a page, but after reloading I have a blank item chosen. How to make remember chosen item?

teacher.html

```
<form id="form"  method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
       <select name="choose_teacher" onChange="this.form.submit();" blank_choice='Please choose:' >
       <option value="{{ 0 }}">blank</option>
           {% for item in query_results %}
               <option value="{{ item.id }}">{{ item.title}} {{ item.name }} {{ item.surname }}</option>
           {% endfor %}
       </select>
</form>
{{ teacher_id }}
```

views.py

```
def teacher(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'choose_teacher' in request.POST:
        teacher_id = request.POST['choose_teacher']
        query_results = Teacher.objects.all()
        context = {'teacher_id': teacher_id,
                   'query_results': query_results}
        return render(request, 'planner/teacher.html', context)
else:
    query_results = Teacher.objects.all()
    context = {'query_results': query_results}
    return render(request, 'planner/teacher.html', context)
```

:edit:

```
    <form id="form" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <select name="choose_teacher" onChange="this.form.submit();">
        {% for item in query_results %}
            <option value="{{ item.id }}"
                    {% ifequal teacher_id item.id %}selected{% endifequal %}>{{ item.title }} {{ item.name }} {{ item.surname }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your template `select` options to:

```
<option value="{{ item.id }}"
{% ifequal teacher_id item.id %}selected{% endifequal %}
>{{ item.title}} {{ item.name }} {{ item.surname }}</option>
```

It will test if the the option id is equal to `teacher_id`, and add the `selected` tag if true.

the same for option 0:

```
<option value="0" {% ifequal teacher_id 0 %}selected{% endifequal %}>blank</option>
```

Comment: It is not working. I've changed it inside my for. And it work as worked before.

Comment: do the same to option 0

Comment: for testing I deleted line with option 0, and still not working

Comment: I've edited and add what I changed. I still don't know why it is not working.

Comment: output your teacher_id and query_results values, let me see them

Comment: both are: 1, 2, 3. I displayed it near name. And below my list. Maybe is something wrong with this view?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100881/discussion-between-bigother-and-user3797879).